# Desktop App using Bowline

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now i trying to develop Desktop application using bowline, ruby.

I used ruby 1.9.2 .I installed bowline gem successfully.And I have created a application using " bowline-gen app helloworld ".Then I run  bowline-bundle. But It make some following Error.

---

/home/users/shamith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bowline-bundler-0.0.4/lib/bowline/bundler/dependency.rb:59:in `<class:Dependency>': undefined method`version_requirements' for class `Bundler::Dependency' (NameError)
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bowline-bundler-0.0.4/lib/bowline/bundler/dependency.rb:4:in`'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bowline-bundler-0.0.4/lib/bowline/bundler/dependency.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bowline-bundler-0.0.4/lib/bowline/bundler.rb:18:in`'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bowline-bundler-0.0.4/bin/bowline-bundle:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/users/shamith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bowline-bundle:19:in`load'

---

please help me to resolve it